# Passing form state in between parent and child in React

Tags: reactjs

What is a good way of passing form values from a child back to a parent in React?

Let's say we have the following example:

```js
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    <Child data={this.state.data[this.state.currentChild]}/>
  },
  getInitialState : function () {
    return {
      data: [{
        field1: 'Text',
        field2: 'Text2'
      }],
      currentChild: 0
    }
  }
});


var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    <div>   
      <input name="field1" value={this.props.data.field1} onChange={this.passBackChanges}/>
      <input name="field2" value={this.props.data.field2} onChange={this.passBackChanges}/>
    </div>
  },
  passBackChanges: function () {
      
  }
});
```

I tried passing in an `onChange` handler from the parent (which fires on `passBackChanges` and in turn updates the Parent's state. However when alternating between the the different children from `Parent` (changing `currentChild` index), the changes don't seem to reflect.

```js
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    <Child data={this.state.data[this.state.currentChild]} onChange={this.updateState}/>
  },
  getInitialState : function () {
    return {
      data: [{
        field1: 'Text',
        field2: 'Text2'
      }],
      currentChild: 0
    }
  },
  updateState: function (state) {
    this.state.data[this.state.currentChild] = state;
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data
    })
  }
});


var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    <div>   
      <input ref="field1" value={this.props.data.field1} onChange={this.passBackChanges}/>
      <input ref="field2" value={this.props.data.field2} onChange={this.passBackChanges}/>
    </div>
  },
  passBackChanges: function () {
      this.props.onChange({
          field1: this.refs.field1.getDOMNode().value,
          field2: this.refs.field2.getDOMNode().value
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: actually found a typo in my original code. It seems that the example I gave does seem to work (pass in callback from parent to Child to listen to change, then rerender the entire tree by passing data as props to the child). seems really dirty though...

Answer (score 0):

setState is the only way to handle state changes.

```js
  updateState (state) {
    let newState = this.state.data;
    newState[this.state.currentChild] = state;
    this.setState({
      data: newState
    })
  }
```